# Correct layout for Json data when searching different attributes

Tags: javascript, json

I have created a data file using JSON. The data is a selection of variables about tube stations. See below for a section of the file.
This setup works very well for finding stations when you have the station id. 
example: when you click on a station on my webpage the elements id is the station code and this allows a popup box to be filled with the stations name and zone.

However, how would it be best to find the location of the station when for example given the full text name? 
a) I would have to have a code iterating through every station object and using an if command check the name in the object against the name given.
b) created a set of key:value pairs in a second javascript object which is first used to lookup the station id then searches in the first object for the rest of the station data.

Also how would I find data on all the stations on a given line.
a) iterate through and check for each that the tubelines array contains the line string
b) Yet another object containing all station codes under a line heading.

```
{
    "BST": {
        "name": "Baker Street",
        "Location": [
            51.523129639184,
            -0.15688978273689
        ],
        "zone": 1,
        "tubelines": [
            "Bakerloo",
            "Circle",
            "Hammersmith & City",
            "District"
        ],
        "Bakerloo": {
            "stepfreetrain": false
        },
        "Circle": {
            "stepfreetrain": false
        },
        "Hammersmith & City": {
            "stepfreetrain": false
        },
        "District": {
            "stepfreetrain": false
        }
    },
    "CHX": {
        "name": "Charing Cross",
        "Location": [
            51.508358644804,
            -0.12478853109718
        ],
        "zone": 1,
        "tubelines": [
            "Bakerloo",
            "Northern"
        ],
        "Bakerloo": {
            "stepfreetrain": true
        },
        "Northern": {
            "stepfreetrain": true
        }
    }
}
```

So the key question is, is this the best way to lay out the data above and if so which is the quickest method to pull out information?

Comment: If you've not looked at it, [JSONPath might be a good solution](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) for searching inside JSON data if you choose not to split up your information into more manageable sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question (was too long to post it as comment):

Create these secondary objects within your "initialization" phase. After generating the objects you can make them accessible via a simple "API". Made a small example (using jQuery and assuming your spots are stored in a spots.json file):

```
var myApp = {

    init: function() {

        // show loading screen while fetching data and creating the "lookup" objects
        showLoader();

        var loadSpots = $.ajax({
            url: "/spots.json"
        });

        loadSpots.done(function(spots) {

            myApp.spots = spots;

            $.each(spots, function(code, details) {
                nameLookup[details.name] = spots[code];
            });

            // All done, hide the loading screen
            hideLoader();

        });

    },

    spots: {},
    nameLookup: {},

    findByCode: function(code) {
        return myApp.spots[code]; 
    },

    findByName: function(name) {
        return myApp.nameLookup[name]; 
    }

};

myApp.init();

// you can then use these API methods to find all information for Baker Street either by name or by code (or by whatever)
myApp.findByCode('BST');
myApp.findByName('Baker Street');
```

Comment: The first time you use nameLookup is when you add a key: value pair. I was under the impression that dictionaries/objects had to be created before they were available to be added to.
either
nameLookup=new Object();
or
person={firstname:"John",lastname:"Doe",age:50,eyecolor:"blue"};

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to put the data of all the separate tube lines inside the "tubelines" property.

For example:

```
{
    "tubelines": {
        "Bakerloo": {
            "stepfreetrain": true
        },
        "Northern": {
            "stepfreetrain": true
        }
    }
}
```

That makes looking up data easier as you can traverse the JSON "tree" for each tube line and find it's data.

Also, I find it easier to name the coordinates "lat" and "long" as separate properties of "Location" (Location.lat, Location.long) vs using an array (Location[0], Location[1]) for readability and eliminating possibility of making mistakes when entering data.

Comment: The reason it was in a separate array was so that I could quickly read every line at the station without the baggage of extra data. Although thinking about it there is probably a quick way to return every key in an object?

Comment: I altered my original answer to fix a syntax error. The tubelines property now is an object of its own. Using a `for (key in tubelines)` loop, you could loop through the `tubelines` property and get all it's keys. Those are the station names. Using `tubelines[key]` gets you its data.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through one only object: slower
Creating multiple objects with different layouts: redundancy (thus possibly error-prone)

If speed of reading the data is more important than high(er) memory consumption write a function to generate several objects designed for your needs at runtime automatically, ONCE. Don't do that manually since it's error-prone and a monkey task. And don't forget to observe changes to your main object (if it can be modified at runtime) so you can regenerate your optimized objects as soon as an entry gets modified. That costs some performance once when starting your application but then you can read from the generated objects fast and easily.

If low memory consumption is more important than speed of finding entries (for example because your application is running on older devices with low memory) just iterate through the entries. I'm not 100% sure if one iteration per lookup uses less memory than creating several different objects and keeping them in memory - it probably depends on the size of your data object.

Looking up keys on the first level of an object is of course always faster than iterating and searching for values deep within an object but it uses more memory since the additional objects must be stored somewhere.

Comment: just to clarify your first suggested method is to use the JSON object (as above or similar) as a master object and create the subsequent objects for rapid find. I think space is not an issue as I am not supporting for particularly old browsers.

Comment: I was planning to import the JSON object after the page had loaded so that users could explore the map faster(either Ajax, or javascript filereader) and it would simply call the data as unavailable. Can creating these secondary objects be done in the background?

Comment: Create these secondary objects within your initialization phase:

Comment: Damn. Too long to post it as comment

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that given the number of tube stations ([270](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Underground)?) that you're not going to notice any particular data arrangement being superior. A simple iteration would be barely noticeable on virtually any platform.

I would rather (as ever) concentrate on making the code legible and easy to manage/maintain, and worry about *specific* performance issues as they arise.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is good advice and its probably going to take some experience to work out when issues of speed arise. Just to clarify I am working on a map with all stations accessible with an oyster card so nearer 600. I also want a set up I can expand to include more data on each station, such as live departures etc.